# Ubuntu don't detect my bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

i have a samsung series 5 book. ubuntu says "No bluetooth adapter found". How can i fix this. im also suspecting that its because of my previous OS, I turn the bluetooth off(using the driver provided by the manufacturer for that OS) and forgot to turn it on before formatting to ubuntu. is there any way to turn bluetooth on in my case? built-in bluetooth device doesn't have a hard switch.

Comment: What is the output of the following commands (please edit your question):  `hcitool dev`, `cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`, `ps aux| grep bluetooth`, `rfkill list`, `bluetoothd -d -n` and the complete `/var/log/dmesg`. You can upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Search **Additional Driver** in dash Open it, It will automatically detect your bluetooth hardware and Suggest you to install driver.

Comment: it only display drivers for the graphics. ATI. i ddnt see driver for bluetooth.